# Create new dataframe columns using values in an existing column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a difficult dataframe problem where I am trying to create new columns / column names / column values out of an existing dataframe that isn't formatted like I want it to be. The data has playerIDs and playerTypes for 4 different players at a time, and looks like this:

```
dput(my.player.data)
structure(list(p_id = c(8470828L, 8478460L, 8470966L, 8475314L, 
8476472L, 8476917L, 8475791L, 8470105L, 8476905L, 8474152L, 8470642L, 
8479325L, 8475218L, 8471296L, 8476874L, 8477943L, 8477934L, 8473432L
), pType = c("Blocker", "Shooter", "Blocker", "Shooter", "Blocker", 
"Hitter", "Blocker", "Shooter", "PlayerID", "PlayerID", "Shooter", 
"Hitter", "PlayerID", "Blocker", "Shooter", "Scorer", "Scorer", 
"Scorer"), p_id1 = c(8475172L, 8470645L, 8474162L, NA, 8480172L, 
8477989L, 8476879L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8474683L, NA, 8476851L, 8469514L, 
8477407L, 8478402L, 8474091L), pType1 = c("Shooter", "Goalie", 
"Shooter", NA, "Shooter", "Hittee", "Shooter", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"Hittee", NA, "Shooter", "Goalie", "Assist", "Assist", "Assist"
), p_id2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 8475246L, 8471729L, 8477018L), pType2 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Assist", 
"Assist", "Assist"), p_id3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8475622L, 8471239L, 8469608L), pType3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Goalie", 
"Goalie", "Goalie")), .Names = c("p_id", "pType", "p_id1", "pType1", 
"p_id2", "pType2", "p_id3", "pType3"), row.names = c(1L, 5001L, 
10001L, 15001L, 20001L, 25001L, 30001L, 35001L, 40001L, 45001L, 
50001L, 55001L, 60001L, 65001L, 70001L, 47329L, 46786L, 45551L
), class = "data.frame")

# ignore that the row numbers are 1, 5000, 10000, etc.

head(my.player.data)
         p_id   pType   p_id1  pType1 p_id2 pType2 p_id3 pType3
1     8470828 Blocker 8475172 Shooter    NA   <NA>    NA   <NA>
5001  8478460 Shooter 8470645  Goalie    NA   <NA>    NA   <NA>
10001 8470966 Blocker 8474162 Shooter    NA   <NA>    NA   <NA>
15001 8475314 Shooter      NA    <NA>    NA   <NA>    NA   <NA>
20001 8476472 Blocker 8480172 Shooter    NA   <NA>    NA   <NA>
25001 8476917  Hitter 8477989  Hittee    NA   <NA>    NA   <NA>
```

There are only a fixed number of pTypes in my data across the 4 pType columns, (Blocker, Shooter, Goalie, etc.) and I would like to create a column for each one of these, with the value in the column equal to the respective playerID.

For example, I'd like something that looks like this:

```
head(better.player.data)
      Blocker  Shooter  Hittee  Hitter  Assist1  Assist2  Scorer  Goalie 
1     8470828  8475172      NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA   
5001       NA  8478460      NA      NA       NA       NA      NA 8470645
10001 8470966  8474162      NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA  
15001      NA  8475314      NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA 
20001 8476472  8480172      NA      NA       NA       NA      NA      NA 
25001      NA       NA 8477989 8476917       NA       NA      NA      NA
```

The main edge-case here is that Assist1 and Assist2 are both labeled as Assist in the my.player.data dataframe (see the last 3 rows, not shown in the head()). I'd like for p_id1 to be Assist1 and p_id2 to be Assist2 (pType1 and pType2 should be the only 2 columns in the original data where the value is Assist (shouldnt be in pType or pType3)

Any help with this, as always, is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I am working on a solution that uses reshape2::dcast - will hopefully have something posted on this soon

Comment: not as straightforward with dcast as I was hoping for...

Comment: Do you really need a column as `PlayerID`? I dont think, presence of `PlayerID` is very meaningful though.

Answer (score 2):

One solution can be achieved using `tidyverse`. The idea is to `gather` convert in long format with `rowname` having matching `pType` and `p_id` columns. First create a group based on number associated with `p_id` and `pType` columns. Perform modification to convert `Assist` to `Assist1` and `Assist2`. Finally, call spread to convert data in desired format.

```
library(tidyverse)


my.player.data %>% rownames_to_column %>%
  mutate(rowname = as.numeric(rowname)) %>%
  gather(Key, Value, -rowname) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Value)) %>%
  mutate(Group = as.integer(gsub("(p_id|pType)","0",Key))) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(Value == "Assist", paste0(Value, Group), Value)) %>%
  mutate(Key =  gsub("\\d","",Key)) %>% #Remove number from p_id and pType columns
  spread(Key, Value) %>% 
  select(-Group) %>% 
  spread(pType, p_id) %>% 
  remove_rownames() %>% 
  column_to_rownames()

#       Assist1 Assist2 Blocker  Goalie  Hittee  Hitter PlayerID  Scorer Shooter
# 1        <NA>    <NA> 8470828    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>    <NA> 8475172
# 5001     <NA>    <NA>    <NA> 8470645    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>    <NA> 8478460
# 10001    <NA>    <NA> 8470966    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>    <NA> 8474162
# 15001    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>    <NA> 8475314
# 20001    <NA>    <NA> 8476472    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>    <NA> 8480172
# 25001    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA> 8477989 8476917     <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
# 30001    <NA>    <NA> 8475791    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>    <NA> 8476879
# 35001    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>    <NA> 8470105
# 40001    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  8476905    <NA>    <NA>
# 45001    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  8474152    <NA>    <NA>
# 45551 8474091 8477018    <NA> 8469608    <NA>    <NA>     <NA> 8473432    <NA>
# 46786 8478402 8471729    <NA> 8471239    <NA>    <NA>     <NA> 8477934    <NA>
# 47329 8477407 8475246    <NA> 8475622    <NA>    <NA>     <NA> 8477943    <NA>
# 50001    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>    <NA> 8470642
# 55001    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA> 8474683 8479325     <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
# 60001    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  8475218    <NA>    <NA>
# 65001    <NA>    <NA> 8471296    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>    <NA> 8476851
# 70001    <NA>    <NA>    <NA> 8469514    <NA>    <NA>     <NA>    <NA> 8476874
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
dcast(na.omit(
             melt(setDT(df)[,id:=1:nrow(df)],"id",list(grep("p_id",names(df)),grep("pType",names(df))))
             ),
        id~value2,value.var = "value1")


    id Assist1 Assist2 Blocker  Goalie  Hittee  Hitter PlayerID  Scorer Shooter
 1:  1      NA      NA 8470828      NA      NA      NA       NA      NA 8475172
 2:  2      NA      NA      NA 8470645      NA      NA       NA      NA 8478460
 3:  3      NA      NA 8470966      NA      NA      NA       NA      NA 8474162
 4:  4      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA      NA 8475314
 5:  5      NA      NA 8476472      NA      NA      NA       NA      NA 8480172
 6:  6      NA      NA      NA      NA 8477989 8476917       NA      NA      NA
 7:  7      NA      NA 8475791      NA      NA      NA       NA      NA 8476879
 8:  8      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA      NA 8470105
 9:  9      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA  8476905      NA      NA
10: 10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA  8474152      NA      NA
11: 11      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA      NA 8470642
12: 12      NA      NA      NA      NA 8474683 8479325       NA      NA      NA
13: 13      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA  8475218      NA      NA
14: 14      NA      NA 8471296      NA      NA      NA       NA      NA 8476851
15: 15      NA      NA      NA 8469514      NA      NA       NA      NA 8476874
16: 16 8477407 8475246      NA 8475622      NA      NA       NA 8477943      NA
17: 17 8478402 8471729      NA 8471239      NA      NA       NA 8477934      NA
18: 18 8474091 8477018      NA 8469608      NA      NA       NA 8473432      NA
```

if you want a base R approach:
 you can do:

```
 as.data.frame.matrix(
      xtabs(p_id~id+pType,
        reshape(transform(df,pType1 =sub("(Assist)","\\11",pType1),pType2 = sub("(Assist)","\\12",pType2), id=1:nrow(df)),matrix(1:(ncol(a)-1),2),dir="long")),
                  row.names(df))


      Assist1 Assist2 Blocker  Goalie  Hittee  Hitter PlayerID  Scorer Shooter
1           0       0 8470828       0       0       0        0       0 8475172
5001        0       0       0 8470645       0       0        0       0 8478460
10001       0       0 8470966       0       0       0        0       0 8474162
15001       0       0       0       0       0       0        0       0 8475314
20001       0       0 8476472       0       0       0        0       0 8480172
25001       0       0       0       0 8477989 8476917        0       0       0
30001       0       0 8475791       0       0       0        0       0 8476879
35001       0       0       0       0       0       0        0       0 8470105
40001       0       0       0       0       0       0  8476905       0       0
45001       0       0       0       0       0       0  8474152       0       0
50001       0       0       0       0       0       0        0       0 8470642
55001       0       0       0       0 8474683 8479325        0       0       0
60001       0       0       0       0       0       0  8475218       0       0
65001       0       0 8471296       0       0       0        0       0 8476851
70001       0       0       0 8469514       0       0        0       0 8476874
47329 8477407 8475246       0 8475622       0       0        0 8477943       0
46786 8478402 8471729       0 8471239       0       0        0 8477934       0
45551 8474091 8477018       0 8469608       0       0        0 8473432       0
```

Comment: Our answers are matching. Hence, these must be correct ways. Good use of `data.table::melt`.

Comment: @MKR all the answeres all the same.. the difference with the rest is the column arrangement.. ours are arranging them alphabetically

Comment: Yes. I had checked and confirmed that my answer was matching with yours. But, as you said, order of rows are a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

We can use`tidyverse::spread` with `reduce`, after some preprocessing as the same row can contain several values for `Assist` :

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  rownames_to_column %>%
  mutate(pType1 = gsub("Assist","Assist1",pType1),
         pType2 = gsub("Assist","Assist2",pType2)) %>%
  reduce(.init= .,.x=1:4,~spread(.,3,2))

#    rowname Blocker  Hitter PlayerID  Scorer Assist1  Hittee Shooter Assist2  Goalie <NA>
# 1        1 8470828      NA       NA      NA      NA      NA 8475172      NA      NA   NA
# 2    10001 8470966      NA       NA      NA      NA      NA 8474162      NA      NA   NA
# 3    15001      NA      NA       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   NA
# 4    20001 8476472      NA       NA      NA      NA      NA 8480172      NA      NA   NA
# 5    25001      NA 8476917       NA      NA      NA 8477989      NA      NA      NA   NA
# 6    30001 8475791      NA       NA      NA      NA      NA 8476879      NA      NA   NA
# 7    35001      NA      NA       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   NA
# 8    40001      NA      NA  8476905      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   NA
# 9    45001      NA      NA  8474152      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   NA
# 10   45551      NA      NA       NA 8473432 8474091      NA      NA 8477018 8469608   NA
# 11   46786      NA      NA       NA 8477934 8478402      NA      NA 8471729 8471239   NA
# 12   47329      NA      NA       NA 8477943 8477407      NA      NA 8475246 8475622   NA
# 13   50001      NA      NA       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   NA
# 14    5001      NA      NA       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   NA
# 15   55001      NA 8479325       NA      NA      NA 8474683      NA      NA      NA   NA
# 16   60001      NA      NA  8475218      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   NA
# 17   65001 8471296      NA       NA      NA      NA      NA 8476851      NA      NA   NA
# 18   70001      NA      NA       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R version:

```
gty <- function(.) unlist(.[grep("pType", names(.))])
# a function to get the vector of "types" from a row of the data frame

# edit: I noticed the "Assist" problem ("Assist1" and "Assist2" in the target table but "Assist" in the source table)
# ... so this needs to be corrected
gty <- function(.) {
  res <- unlist(.[grep("pType", names(.))])
  res[res %in% "Assist"] <- paste0("Assist", 1:sum(res%in%"Assist"))
  res
}
# or in a hyper-functional style
gty <- function(.){ (function(..) {"[<-" (.., ..%in%"Assist", paste0("Assist", 1:sum(..%in%"Assist")))})(unlist(.[grep("pType", names(.))]))}


gid <- function(.) as.numeric(unlist(.[grep("_id", names(.))]))
# a function to get the vector of "ids" from a row of the data frame
# as.numeric - needed if this will be used from within `apply`as I intend to

types <- c("Blocker", "Shooter", "Hittee", "Hitter", "Assist1", "Assist2", 
         "Scorer", "Goalie")
# a list of types

fun <- function(.)  setNames(gid(.)[match(types, gty(.))], types)
# a function which gets the ids and types from a row and rearranges them

t(apply(df, 1, fun))
```

And the result:

```
      Blocker Shooter  Hittee  Hitter Assist1 Assist2  Scorer  Goalie
1     8470828 8475172      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
5001       NA 8478460      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA 8470645
10001 8470966 8474162      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
15001      NA 8475314      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
20001 8476472 8480172      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
25001      NA      NA 8477989 8476917      NA      NA      NA      NA
30001 8475791 8476879      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
35001      NA 8470105      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
40001      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
45001      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
50001      NA 8470642      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
55001      NA      NA 8474683 8479325      NA      NA      NA      NA
60001      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
65001 8471296 8476851      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
70001      NA 8476874      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA 8469514
47329      NA      NA      NA      NA 8477407 8475246 8477943 8475622
46786      NA      NA      NA      NA 8478402 8471729 8477934 8471239
45551      NA      NA      NA      NA 8474091 8477018 8473432 8469608
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the creative answer I was looking for, but this technically works for me:

```
my.player.data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Shooter = ifelse(pType == "Shooter", p_id, ifelse(pType1 == "Shooter", p_id1, ifelse(pType2 == "Shooter", p_id2, ifelse(pType3 == "Shooter", p_id3, NA))))) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Goalie = ifelse(pType == "Goalie", p_id, ifelse(pType1 == "Goalie", p_id1, ifelse(pType2 == "Goalie", p_id2, ifelse(pType3 == "Goalie", p_id3, NA))))) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Blocker = ifelse(pType == "Blocker", p_id, ifelse(pType1 == "Blocker", p_id1, ifelse(pType2 == "Blocker", p_id2, ifelse(pType3 == "Blocker", p_id3, NA)))))
  dplyr::mutate(Assister1 = ifelse(pType1 == "Assist", p_id1, NA)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Assister1 = ifelse(pType2 == "Assist", p_id2, NA))
```